# Is there anything like Java's AtomicStampedReference in C++?

Tags: java, c++, atomic, lock-free, aba

I am learning lock-free structure, and I noticed an ABA problem.

I think Java's [`AtomicStampedReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicStampedReference.html) can solve this problem.

So, is there anything similar in C++ that can solve this?

Comment: Can you link to the Java docs about what that is?  (reminder: [edit] your question to make that word a link, don't just answer in comments)

Comment: Considering Java is a cheap knock-off of C++ there probably is - just explain in laymans terms what AtomicStampedReference is so we know what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can you explain the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @RemyLebeau  i want to solve ABA problem in CAS lock free queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a direct equivalent. You could implement it yourself, the source for `AtomicStampedReference` is here: https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicStampedReference.java

You could probably implement this in c++ maybe making use of [`std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2) to implement the `private volatile Pair<V> pair`.

If you don't need the full functionality of `AtomicStampedReference` you can probably use `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr>` directly in your code. If you don't have c++20 then you can use the previous stand-alone atomic `shared_ptr` [functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic)

Comment: The problem with the C++11 `std::atomic_...<std::shared_ptr>` functions is that they're not lock-free in any implementations, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at [`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic). I have never heard of "AtomicStampedReference", but from just a cursory look, it seems to be an atomic reference. `std::atomic` is for atomic variables. Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Comment: got it, I have found i can wrap the struct to atomic<T>. Thank you

Comment: @nickhuang note that `std::atomic` will almost certainly use a mutex for when `T` is not one of the built in types

Comment: @AlanBirtles: Some targets support lock-free `atomic<T>` for structs that are 2 pointers wide.  Especially 32-bit targets like modern ARMv8, and 32-bit x86.  Modern GCC for x86-64 doesn't inline `lock cmpxchg16b` but libatomic will use it instead of a mutex.  (But it uses it even for pure loads when you only care about one member.  You can hack around that with a union: [How can I implement ABA counter with c++11 CAS?](//stackoverflow.com/a/38991835)).  Anyway, in general a struct will be lock-free if its size is a small power of 2, even if it has multiple smaller members.

Comment: A little bit of googling would reveal that AtomicStampedReference is Java's atomic reference + stamp that helps avoid the ABA problem in lock-free programming.